# Create generic class instance throws TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

My TestLayer class has the namespace: "BLL.Infrastructure.TestLayer" and is inside the assembly: "BLL"

```
public class LayerFactory<T, U>
{

  public static IBaseLayer<T, U> Get()
  {
       var obj = Activator.CreateInstance("BLL", "BLL.Infrastructure.TestLayer", new object[]   { (IBaseLayer<T, U>)null });


  }
}
```

When I run the code the Activator throws an TypeLoadException with no more details

Thats the concrete class it should create:

GenericBaseLayer implements the IBaseLayer.

```
public class TestLayer<T, U> : GenericBaseLayer<MyRequest, MyInfo.ActionType>
{
  public TestLayer(IBaseLayer<MyRequest, MyInfo.ActionType> layer)
            : base(layer)
   { }
}
```

What do I wrong?

The LayerFactory is inside the Assembly: BLL

Therefore the assembly must be already loaded!

**Update**

```
Type d1 = typeof(TestLayer<,>);
Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(T), typeof(U) };
Type constructed = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed, new object[] { (IBaseLayer<T, U>)null });
```

This works :)

Comment: The exception has more details in the InnerException property. The static ctor of GenericBaseLayer threw.

Comment: There is not more, the InnerException is NULL

Comment: Ok then press ctrl-alt-e and make the debugger break on all exceptions right when they occur (might have gotten the shortcut wrong).

Comment: What should that help? (oc I tried this tip) I always break at the TypeLoadException because the testlayer could not be loaded...

Comment: The `TestLayout` class expects two generic arguments, right? I don't seem them passed anywhere to the `CreateInstance` method you're calling. In fact, it seems you're not using those generic arguments (`<T, U>` in your `TestLayout` code) at all, as you're passing the actual types `MyRequest` and `MyInfo.ActionType` to the respective type parameters of the base class.

Comment: Right! 2 generic arguments T and U. How do you pass them? I just passed the IBaseLayer<T,U> as the constructor parameter for the TestLayer.

Comment: I'm not sure how to specify that as a string, but as the `TestLayer` type (sorry for the typos in my message - I meant `Layer` all the way, not `Layout` ...) is already compile-time-accessible in your `LayerFactory` class, I'd go with the `typeof(TestLayer<,>)` way, call [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) on that `Type` instance and use a `CreateInstance` overload that takes a `Type`. If that solves your problem, I can also post it as a properly formatted answer.

Comment: See my update and use it as solution :P

Comment: ah wait O.R.Mapper. Because I have many TestLayer class with just different namespace the typeof(TestLayer<,>); wants to know which namespace.class to use. When all classes are the same (same ctor parameter + type) should that matter which TestLayer I choose?

Comment: It does matter a lot; in fact, the compiler doesn't care whether the classes happen to have the same class name or not. You have to know at design time which `TestLayer` class to use for this approach to work.

Comment: Yes I just tested it and it does not work because the wrong layer is created. I really need to create the TestLayer from the assembly and namespace.class like posted initially. I can not MakeGenericType on TestLayer<> which could be any TestLayer from many...

Comment: I have added an answer that hopefully works around the problem by using the string representation of the generic type definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the type name string as indicated [here](http://todotnet.com/post/2006/11/13/Instantiating-Generic-Types-at-runtime.aspx): That article suggests

```
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"
```

is the string identifier for a `List<string>`.

If you know `T` and `U` only at runtime, you can still use `Type.GetType` with the string representation of the generic type definition:

```
Type d1 = Type.GetType(yourNamespace + ".TestLayer`2");
```

You can then call `MakeGenericType` on `d1` as shown in the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240407/type-gettype-does-not-work-on-generic-classes LOL... just before you posted... What is this "`2" in your string parameter?

Comment: @Elisa: Yes; at first, I tried to explain that, but somehow, the SO markup wouldn't let me (as ` and opening pointed bracket are special characters there).