# Type.GetType does not work on generic classes?

Tags: c#, reflection, types

```
Type t = Type.GetType("BLL.MyLayers.TestLayer,BLL");
```

t is always null for a generic class.

When I try to get the type for a normal class t is not null.

Why is that or do I something wrong?

Comment: have you tried `Type t = Type.GetType("BLL.MyLayers.TestLayer<>,BLL");` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generic types are compiled using a little trick:

```
class A<T>
{
}

var aa = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication1.A`1");
```

Note that the apostrophe isn't a quote, but the key to the left of the 1 key (on most keyboards).

Comment: Thanks its "`2" on my side as 2 generic params.

Comment: @Elisa in that case the c# syntax is not `<>` but instead: `<,>`

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("BLL.MyLayers.TestLayer`1,BLL");
```